# Integration with respect to Cylinder Measures in infinite dimensional real Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

I am stuck on some question that came to mind. I am trying to make sense of integrations of cylinder functions w.r.t cylinder measures. First refer to this to understand what I am willing to ask(my question is at the end):

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space, $dim(H)=\infty$. Let $\mathcal{P}_H$ be the set of all finite dimensional orthogonal projections $P$ of $H$. We introduce the following definition.

A Cylinder set in $H$ is a subset of $H$ of the form $C=\left\{x\in H : Px\in B\right\}$ where $P \in\mathcal{P}_H$ and $B\in $ Bor$(PH)$.

Now, we know that 
Given $P\in \mathcal{P}_H$, let $C_P=\left\{P^{-1}(B):B\in Bor(PH)\right\}$.Then
$C_P$ is a $\sigma$-algebra , and $$\mathcal{C}_H = \bigcup_P C_P$$ is an algebra. Furthermore, $\sigma(\mathcal{C}_H) =$Bor$(H)$.

Now we have the following definition of a cylinder measure: A Cylinder measure on $H$ is finitely additive function $\Pi:\mathcal{C}_H \rightarrow [0,1]$ with $\Pi(H)=1$ such that $\left.\Pi\right|_{C_P}$ is countably additive , $\forall P\in \mathcal{P}_H$.

I would like to integrate with respect to cylinder measures, and this can be done with cylinder functions based at P. $f:H\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be a cylinder function if is $C_P$ measurable for some $P\in\mathcal{P}_H$.
Such a function is said to be based at $P$.

The cylinder functions based in $P$ are precisely the real valued functions on $H$ of the form $f= \phi\circ P$ , where $\phi:PH\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable.

Then given a cylinder function based at $P$ and a cylinder measure $\Pi$, we are now able to makes sense of the integral given as $$\int_H fd\Pi=\int_H \phi\circ P d\Pi=\int _{PH} \phi d\Pi_{PH}$$, where $\Pi_{PH}=\Pi\circ P^{-1}$.

My question is: If $f$ is a cylinder function based at $P$ but also based at $P^{'}$ where $P^{'}>P$, then does the integral remain unchanged when replacing $P$ by $P^{'}$? It should be true in order to makes sense, but how do I actually prove it? would appreciate if anyone could provide a justification for this.

Comment: not relevant anymore . I got this . Thanks everyone for your huge help .